# Matplotlib's get_ticklabels not working with custom string labels

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I would like to plot only every 50th item from "dates" as a tick on the x axis. When I comment out the line "plt.xticks(xticks, dates)", it works fine (top figure), but when I attempt to replace the numbers with the actual date strings, it puts ALL the dates instead of only every 50th ones (bottom figure).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, date
import numpy as np

vals = [10, 11, 10, 6, 7, 4, 4, 6, 2, 3, 11, 11, 8, 8, 6, 9, 8, 8, 6, 6, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 7, 4, 8, 5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 4, 9, 6, 6, 5, 14, 17, 13, 11, 5, 7, 11, 7, 9, 6, 3, 7, 5, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 1]

dates =['05/01/2018', '05/02/2018', '05/03/2018', '05/04/2018', '05/05/2018', '05/06/2018', '05/07/2018', '05/08/2018', '05/09/2018', '05/10/2018', '05/11/2018', '05/12/2018', '05/13/2018', '05/14/2018', '05/15/2018', '05/16/2018', '05/17/2018', '05/18/2018', '05/19/2018', '05/20/2018', '05/21/2018', '05/22/2018', '05/23/2018', '05/24/2018', '05/25/2018', '05/26/2018', '05/27/2018', '05/28/2018', '05/29/2018', '05/30/2018', '05/31/2018', '06/01/2018', '06/02/2018', '06/03/2018', '06/04/2018', '06/05/2018', '06/06/2018', '06/07/2018', '06/08/2018', '06/09/2018', '06/10/2018', '06/11/2018', '06/12/2018', '06/13/2018', '06/14/2018', '06/15/2018', '06/16/2018', '06/17/2018', '06/18/2018', '06/19/2018', '06/20/2018', '06/21/2018', '06/22/2018', '06/23/2018', '06/24/2018', '06/25/2018', '06/26/2018', '06/27/2018', '06/28/2018', '06/29/2018', '06/30/2018', '07/01/2018', '07/02/2018', '07/03/2018', '07/04/2018', '07/05/2018', '07/06/2018', '07/07/2018', '07/08/2018', '07/09/2018', '07/10/2018', '07/11/2018', '07/12/2018', '07/13/2018', '07/14/2018', '07/15/2018', '07/16/2018', '07/17/2018', '07/18/2018', '07/19/2018', '07/20/2018', '07/21/2018', '07/22/2018', '07/23/2018', '07/24/2018', '07/25/2018', '07/26/2018', '07/27/2018', '07/28/2018', '07/29/2018', '07/30/2018', '07/31/2018', '08/01/2018', '08/02/2018', '08/03/2018', '08/04/2018', '08/05/2018', '08/06/2018', '08/07/2018', '08/08/2018', '08/09/2018', '08/10/2018', '08/11/2018', '08/12/2018', '08/13/2018', '08/14/2018', '08/15/2018', '08/16/2018', '08/17/2018', '08/18/2018', '08/19/2018', '08/21/2018', '08/22/2018', '08/23/2018', '08/24/2018', '08/25/2018', '08/26/2018', '08/27/2018', '08/28/2018', '08/29/2018', '08/30/2018', '08/31/2018', '09/01/2018', '09/06/2018', '09/07/2018', '09/08/2018', '09/09/2018', '09/10/2018', '09/11/2018', '09/12/2018', '09/13/2018', '09/14/2018', '09/15/2018', '09/16/2018', '09/17/2018', '09/18/2018', '09/19/2018', '09/20/2018', '09/21/2018', '09/22/2018', '09/23/2018', '09/24/2018', '09/25/2018', '09/26/2018', '09/27/2018', '09/28/2018', '09/29/2018', '09/30/2018', '10/01/2018', '10/02/2018', '10/03/2018', '10/04/2018', '10/05/2018', '10/06/2018', '10/07/2018', '10/08/2018', '10/09/2018', '10/10/2018', '10/11/2018', '10/12/2018', '10/13/2018', '10/14/2018', '10/15/2018', '10/16/2018', '10/17/2018', '10/18/2018', '10/19/2018', '10/20/2018', '10/21/2018', '10/22/2018', '10/23/2018', '10/24/2018', '10/25/2018', '10/28/2018', '10/29/2018', '10/30/2018', '10/31/2018', '11/01/2018', '11/02/2018', '11/03/2018', '11/04/2018', '11/05/2018', '11/06/2018', '11/07/2018', '11/08/2018', '11/09/2018', '11/10/2018', '11/11/2018', '11/12/2018', '11/13/2018', '11/14/2018', '11/15/2018', '11/16/2018', '11/22/2018', '11/23/2018', '11/25/2018', '11/26/2018', '11/27/2018', '11/29/2018', '12/01/2018', '12/02/2018', '12/05/2018']
    xticks = np.arange(len(vals))

    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.bar(xticks,vals)
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.xticks(xticks, dates)
    for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::50]:
        label.set_visible(True)

    plt.show()
```

[image: Here, works fine when the ticks are just the numbers and line is commented out.]

[image: Here, the selection of only every 50th tick does not work and all dates are shown when we add back the conversion from number to date]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
ax = plt.axes()

pos = np.arange(len(vals))
ax.bar(pos, vals)

ax.set_xticks(pos[::50])
ax.set_xticklabels(np.array(dates)[::50], rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to set every 50th label visible. But all the others are visible anyways, so all are visible, plus those you set visible. Of course you could instead set some **in**visible; but maybe a better solution is to not even create the labels in the first place?

To tick and label every 50th entry you can slice the lists of ticks and labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, date
import numpy as np

vals = [10, 11, ....]
dates =['05/01/2018', '05/02/2018', ....]
xticks = np.arange(len(vals))

ax = plt.axes()
ax.bar(xticks,vals)

plt.xticks(xticks[::50], dates[::50], rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note however, that just plotting the dates as datetimes would give you some very nice formatting automatically.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

vals = [10, 11, ..., 1]
dates =['05/01/2018', '05/02/2018', ..., '12/05/2018']
dates = [datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y") for s in dates]

ax = plt.axes()
ax.bar(dates,vals)

plt.show()
```

[image]