# Python plot use only every nth element of x to label the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Sorry, probabely this question was asked and answered thousands of times, but somehow I can't find the solution.

I have two lists:

```
x=['text', 'some more text', 'looooong text']
y = [1, 2, 3]
```

When I plot them with

```
plt.plot(x,y)
```

the texts of my x list are not readible because they cover each other up.

What have I to do to show only 'text' and 'looooooong text' on my x-axis?
Probabely something with xticks, but I don't get it.

Comment: See e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641430/matplotlibs-get-ticklabels-not-working-with-custom-string-labels/53641593#53641593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(3), ['text','','looooong text'])
```

[image]

If you want to preserve all x labels without overlapping then use:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))  # <- increase figure margin
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.tight_layout()   # <- helps to maintain non-overlapping
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! When I played around with xticks, I accidentally overwrote it and was wondering about the strange error messages afterwards. But after I figured that out, your answer worked perfectly for me!